# Error When Upload Document in Drop Off Library

Tags: drop-off-library, ootb

Hy.

I had Activated Content Organizer Feature to Move Document from Drop Off Library to Another Library.

I had created rule to move Document.

But,When I upload the Document in Drop Off Library it gives following error

" 0x80070057Invalid data has been used to update the list item. The field you are trying to update may be read only."

& that Document in Destination Library but Metadata is not updated.

Comment: Is there any read only column?

Comment: No.Not any Custom Column.Only Title Column is there.

Comment: Are you able to add the document directly to the library?

Comment: No.Its give Following Error
"Value does not fall within the expected range"

Comment: Can you try with some other library, i think there is some issue with document library?

Comment: I had try with other library & other Content Type also.
But same Result.

Comment: Try following: Central Administration > Application Management > Manage Web Applications select the Web Application in use and choose: “General Settings > Resource Throttling” via the Ribbon. In that scroll down and look for "List View Lookup Threshold" in that by default value is 8 increase and test.

Comment: Change to 12 but same Result.

Answer (score 0):

This article explains how to use the drop off library.

https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Create-Content-Organizer-rules-to-route-documents-1e4d37a3-635d-4764-b0fc-f7c5356c1900